# Place Chart to container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag

I have here an example of AmCharts, i have made drag n drop function, but i need to place chart into container and fit a size. Does anybody know? Thanks for help

here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ngg2f5gz/1/

drag n drop function

```
$( function() {
    $( "#chartdiv" ).draggable();
    $( "#container" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
$( "#container" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    # clear the container
    $(this).html('');

    # append chart to container
    ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));

    # modify some css to fit
    ui.draggable.css({
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      position: 'absolute'
    });

    # destroy draggable after chart was dropped
    ui.draggable.draggable('destroy');
  }
});
```

And also add `position: relative;` to `#container`'s css rules.

Comment: @Michal after it was placed into a `container`? Just remove `ui.draggable.draggable('destroy');`

Comment: You lost draggable initializer somewhere, add `$('#chartdiv').draggable();` before whole code